# Bootstrap Template in ASP.NET: Blank spaces around the template

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm adding Gentelella template to my project. The steps followed so far are:

**Steps:**

- Add the template via bower
- Edit the _Layout.cshtml: The info from the main page of the template (`head` and `body`) were copied to the _Layout.
- The project is routed to call the Home Controller and Index action first. The Index page was left blank.

**The result:**

There is empty padding around the main content.

[image]

**Question:**

How can I identify which component of the project is creating these spaces around the template?

*Note:* I haven't touch anything from the enviroment section.

**Code:**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>

      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <title>Gentelella Alela! | </title>
      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="~/lib/gentelella/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Font Awesome -->
      <link href="~/lib/gentelella/vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- NProgress -->
      <link href="~/lib/gentelella/vendors/nprogress/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
      <link href="~/lib/gentelella/build/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <environment names="Development,Staging,Production">

      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
      <script src="~/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
      <script src="~/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
      <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>


      <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap-lumen.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/nestednavbar.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
  </environment>
  @RenderSection("css", required: false)
  </head>

  <body class="nav-md">
      @RenderBody()
      @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
      //..Template code
  </body>      
  </html>
```

***Edit***: Source code generated

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <head>

          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
          <!-- Meta, title, CSS, favicons, etc. -->
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <title>Gentelella Alela! | </title>
          <!-- Bootstrap -->
          <link href="/lib/gentelella/vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <!-- Font Awesome -->
          <link href="/lib/gentelella/vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <!-- NProgress -->
          <link href="/lib/gentelella/vendors/nprogress/nprogress.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <!-- Custom Theme Style -->
          <link href="/lib/gentelella/build/css/custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet">





          <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
          <script src="/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js?v=qcV1wr-bn4NoBtxYqghmy1WIBvxeoe8vQlCowLG-cng"></script>
          <script src="/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js?v=X_58s5WblGMAw9SpDtqnV8dLRNCawsyGwNqnZD0Je_s"></script>
          <script src="/js/site.js?v=ViqmmChOp_51fH3dM_KEQAFClKU0vp0UrxlREwyHKHc"></script>


          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-lumen.css" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/nestednavbar.css" />
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />


  </head>
  <body class="nav-md">


      <div class="container body">
          <div class="main_container">
              <div class="col-md-3 left_col">
                  <div class="left_col scroll-view">
                      <div class="navbar nav_title" style="border: 0;">
                          <a href="index.html" class="site_title"><i class="fa fa-paw"></i> <span>Gentelella Alela!</span></a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                      <!-- menu profile quick info -->
                      <div class="profile clearfix">
                          <div class="profile_pic">
                              <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="..." class="img-circle profile_img">
                          </div>
                          <div class="profile_info">
                              <span>Bienvenido,</span>
                              <h2>Luis Alberto</h2>
                          </div>
                          <div class="clearfix"></div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /menu profile quick info -->
                      <br />
                      <!-- sidebar menu -->
                      <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
                          <div class="menu_section">
                              <h3>General</h3>
                              <ul class="nav side-menu">
                                  <li>
                                      <a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Reportes <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                      <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                          <li><a href="index.html">Ventas</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="index2.html">Rentabilidad</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="index3.html">Presupuestos</a></li>
                                      </ul>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                      <a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Tiendas <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                      <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                          <li><a href="/Stores">Nueva Tienda</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="form_advanced.html">Editar Tiendas</a></li>
                                      </ul>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                      <a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Forms <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                      <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                          <li><a href="form.html">General Form</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="form_advanced.html">Advanced Components</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="form_validation.html">Form Validation</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="form_wizards.html">Form Wizard</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="form_upload.html">Form Upload</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="form_buttons.html">Form Buttons</a></li>
                                      </ul>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                      <a><i class="fa fa-desktop"></i> UI Elements <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                      <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                          <li><a href="general_elements.html">General Elements</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="media_gallery.html">Media Gallery</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="typography.html">Typography</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="icons.html">Icons</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="glyphicons.html">Glyphicons</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="widgets.html">Widgets</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="invoice.html">Invoice</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="inbox.html">Inbox</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="calendar.html">Calendar</a></li>
                                      </ul>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                      <a><i class="fa fa-table"></i> Tables <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                      <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                          <li><a href="tables.html">Tables</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="tables_dynamic.html">Table Dynamic</a></li>
                                      </ul>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                      <a><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i> Data Presentation <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                      <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                          <li><a href="chartjs.html">Chart JS</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="chartjs2.html">Chart JS2</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="morisjs.html">Moris JS</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="echarts.html">ECharts</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="other_charts.html">Other Charts</a></li>
                                      </ul>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                      <a><i class="fa fa-clone"></i>Layouts <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                      <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                          <li><a href="fixed_sidebar.html">Fixed Sidebar</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="fixed_footer.html">Fixed Footer</a></li>
                                      </ul>
                                  </li>
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                          <div class="menu_section">
                              <h3>Live On</h3>
                              <ul class="nav side-menu">
                                  <li>
                                      <a><i class="fa fa-bug"></i> Additional Pages <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                      <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                          <li><a href="e_commerce.html">E-commerce</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="project_detail.html">Project Detail</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>
                                      </ul>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                      <a><i class="fa fa-windows"></i> Extras <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                      <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                          <li><a href="page_403.html">403 Error</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="page_404.html">404 Error</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="page_500.html">500 Error</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="plain_page.html">Plain Page</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="login.html">Login Page</a></li>
                                          <li><a href="pricing_tables.html">Pricing Tables</a></li>
                                      </ul>
                                  </li>
                                  <li>
                                      <a><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> Multilevel Menu <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                      <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                          <li><a href="#level1_1">Level One</a>
                                          <li>
                                              <a>Level One<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                              <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                                  <li class="sub_menu">
                                                      <a href="level2.html">Level Two</a>
                                                  </li>
                                                  <li>
                                                      <a href="#level2_1">Level Two</a>
                                                  </li>
                                                  <li>
                                                      <a href="#level2_2">Level Two</a>
                                                  </li>
                                              </ul>
                                          </li>
                                          <li>
                                              <a href="#level1_2">Level One</a>
                                          </li>
                                      </ul>
                                  </li>
                                  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> Landing Page <span class="label label-success pull-right">Coming Soon</span></a></li>
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /sidebar menu -->
                      <!-- /menu footer buttons -->
                      <div class="sidebar-footer hidden-small">
                          <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Settings">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                          </a>
                          <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="FullScreen">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                          </a>
                          <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Lock">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                          </a>
                          <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Logout" href="login.html">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                          </a>
                      </div>
                      <!-- /menu footer buttons -->
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- top navigation -->
              <div class="top_nav">
                  <div class="nav_menu">
                      <nav>
                          <div class="nav toggle">
                              <a id="menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                          </div>
                          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                              <li class="">
                                  <a href="javascript:;" class="user-profile dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                      <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="">John Doe
                                      <span class=" fa fa-angle-down"></span>
                                  </a>
                                  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-usermenu pull-right">
                                      <li><a href="javascript:;"> Profile</a></li>
                                      <li>
                                          <a href="javascript:;">
                                              <span class="badge bg-red pull-right">50%</span>
                                              <span>Settings</span>
                                          </a>
                                      </li>
                                      <li><a href="javascript:;">Help</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out pull-right"></i> Log Out</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                              </li>
                              <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                                  <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle info-number" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                      <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                                      <span class="badge bg-green">6</span>
                                  </a>
                                  <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu list-unstyled msg_list" role="menu">
                                      <li>
                                          <a>
                                              <span class="image"><img src="images/img.jpg" alt="Profile Image" /></span>
                                              <span>
                                                  <span>John Smith</span>
                                                  <span class="time">3 mins ago</span>
                                              </span>
                                              <span class="message">
                                                  Film festivals used to be do-or-die moments for movie makers. They were where...
                                              </span>
                                          </a>
                                      </li>
                                      <li>
                                          <a>
                                              <span class="image"><img src="images/img.jpg" alt="Profile Image" /></span>
                                              <span>
                                                  <span>John Smith</span>
                                                  <span class="time">3 mins ago</span>
                                              </span>
                                              <span class="message">
                                                  Film festivals used to be do-or-die moments for movie makers. They were where...
                                              </span>
                                          </a>
                                      </li>
                                      <li>
                                          <a>
                                              <span class="image"><img src="images/img.jpg" alt="Profile Image" /></span>
                                              <span>
                                                  <span>John Smith</span>
                                                  <span class="time">3 mins ago</span>
                                              </span>
                                              <span class="message">
                                                  Film festivals used to be do-or-die moments for movie makers. They were where...
                                              </span>
                                          </a>
                                      </li>
                                      <li>
                                          <a>
                                              <span class="image"><img src="images/img.jpg" alt="Profile Image" /></span>
                                              <span>
                                                  <span>John Smith</span>
                                                  <span class="time">3 mins ago</span>
                                              </span>
                                              <span class="message">
                                                  Film festivals used to be do-or-die moments for movie makers. They were where...
                                              </span>
                                          </a>
                                      </li>
                                      <li>
                                          <div class="text-center">
                                              <a>
                                                  <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                                                  <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                                              </a>
                                          </div>
                                      </li>
                                  </ul>
                              </li>
                          </ul>
                      </nav>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /top navigation -->
              <!-- page content -->
              <div class="right_col" role="main">
                  <div class="">
                      <div class="page-title">
                          <div class="title_left">
                              <h3>Plain Page</h3>
                          </div>
                          <div class="title_right">
                              <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 form-group pull-right top_search">
                                  <div class="input-group">
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                                          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
                                      </span>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                      <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                              <div class="x_panel">
                                  <div class="x_title">
                                      <h2>Plain Page</h2>
                                      <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                                          <li>
                                              <a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                                          </li>
                                          <li class="dropdown">
                                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                                              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                                  <li>
                                                      <a href="#">Settings 1</a>
                                                  </li>
                                                  <li>
                                                      <a href="#">Settings 2</a>
                                                  </li>
                                              </ul>
                                          </li>
                                          <li>
                                              <a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                                          </li>
                                      </ul>
                                      <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                  </div>
                                  <div class="x_content">
                                      Add content to the page ...
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <!-- /page content -->
              <!-- footer content -->
              <footer>
                  <div class="pull-right">
                      Gentelella - Bootstrap Admin Template by <a href="https://colorlib.com">Colorlib</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
              </footer>
              <!-- /footer content -->
          </div>
      </div>
      <!-- jQuery -->
      <script src="/lib/gentelella/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <script src="/lib/gentelella/vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <!-- FastClick -->
      <script src="/lib/gentelella/vendors/fastclick/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
      <!-- NProgress -->
      <script src="/lib/gentelella/vendors/nprogress/nprogress.js"></script>

      <!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
      <script src="/lib/gentelella/build/js/custom.min.js"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: can you show as html generated in browser, copy from browser view source

Comment: @Nezir It is done. Thanks.

Comment: I've compared both the _Layout code and the source code of the final view and they both look the same. I was expecting some difference between them but none

Comment: I cant find cdn for /lib/gentelella/build/css/custom.min.css what is this file is it some  custom yours code?

Comment: @Nezir I removed the reference for <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" /> inside the enviroment section and the top padding is gone. lateral padding still persists.

Comment: @Nezir That file came with gentelella

Comment: Look it is hard to recreate page because of this  dependencies, but I suggesting you to use chrome inspect and investigating the surround div and there css classes

Comment: I've fixed it but removing <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/bootstrap-lumen.css" /> which was the original template I used for the project. As you were saying, it was about checking the css classess. Leave an answer if you like :)

Comment: @Nezir Got another question around here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52548784/bootstrap-template-using-the-template-for-all-the-views if you are free :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you managed to do it was about investigating and removing some css classes or files that has some unneeded margin or padding.