# Bootstrap Template: Using the template for all the views

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add the Gentelella template to my ASP.NET Core project.

The main problem is that the content of my current pages (any index page) is not merged with the template:

***Expected Value:***

[image]

***Current Value:***

[image]

**The problem:**

I'm trying to figure out how to show these components (index view inside and layout) together, as shown in picture 1.

For this, I found the code inside the _Layout that encapsulates the `Plain Page` section:

Should I make the call of my index view in that section? How?

*PartialView* rings a bell.

**Calling the Controllers and actions:**

```
                              <li>
                                  <a><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Tiendas <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                  <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                      <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Stores" asp-action="Index">Nueva Tienda</a></li>
                                      <li><a href="~/Shared/_Navbar.cshtml">Editar Tiendas</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                              </li>
```

**Section inside the Template where the Index should show:**

```
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                          <div class="x_panel">
                              <div class="x_title">
                                  <h2>Plain Page</h2>
                                  <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                                      <li>
                                          <a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                                      </li>
                                      <li class="dropdown">
                                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                                          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                              <li>
                                                  <a href="#">Settings 1</a>
                                              </li>
                                              <li>
                                                  <a href="#">Settings 2</a>
                                              </li>
                                          </ul>
                                      </li>
                                      <li>
                                          <a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                                      </li>
                                  </ul>
                                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="x_content">
                                  Add content to the page ...
                              </div>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
```

**Example of Index View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Application.Models.Tienda>
    @using Application.Models
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    }
    @Html.Partial("_NavBar")



    <h2>Tiendas</h2>
@*data-toggle tells bootstrap what to do*@
@*data-target tells bootstrap which element is going to open*@
    <div class="btn-group" id="modalbutton">
        <a id="createEditStoreModal" data-toggle="modal" asp-action="Create" data-target="#modal-action-store"
            class="btn btn-primary">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>  Nueva Tienda
            </a>
    </div>
    <p></p>
    <table id="stores" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Provincia
                </th>
                <th>
                    Marca Comercial
                </th>
                <th>
                    Cadena
                </th>
                <th>
                    Tienda
                </th>
                <th>Editar</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Districts.Provincias.provincia_nombre)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tienda_marca)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tienda_cadena)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.tienda_nombre)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="btn-group" id="modalbuttonedit">
                            <a id="editStoreModal" data-toggle="modal" asp-action="Create"
                                data-target="#modal-action-store" asp-route-id="@item.tienda_id" class="btn btn-info">Edit</a>
                        </div>

                    </td>
                </tr>}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: can you please  install this took ngrok https://ngrok.com/download and check how to run it, after that you can send me generated url so I can connect to you development site on your pc and check this template issues?

Comment: or in general for templating in your asp.net project _Layout.cshtml file you should insert the whole code from template index or layout file. The code which is over the <body> and below </body>  code.  The content inside <body> </body>  you should put into your index.cshtml or any other routed page you wish to show i url.

Comment: Yes. In fact, I'm editing the buttons of the navbar to call the controllers and actions needed. The problem comes when rendering the information. Instead of going to the body of the template it goes on top. I can't just put the href for the html since it has to access the DB thru the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

The proper way to position your Index view inside the _Layout is using the `@RenderBody()` wherever you want to load your view information.

In this case, it was where I indicated it in the question.

There is also the option to render your scripts, if any. `@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)`

We have to be careful with that since the script might run locally but not once the project is in production because of bad placement.

The final picture is this:

[image]